# Issue with URL RewriteRule

Tags: url, mod-rewrite

I'm using this `RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/ page.php?id=$1` to change the URL http://example.com/page.php?id=00001 into http://example.com/page/00001/ although any images or CSS/JS/etc pages are not correctly linked any more.

EG: http://example.com/_img/image.jpg is turned into http://example.com/page/00001/_img/image.jpg

Is there a way to change the whole directory as well? For example, I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/(.*?) $2
```

But that didn't work. Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**
Okay, this seems to work, but only one of them work depending which is first.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ $2
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/ page.php?id=$1
```

This way it ignores the second one, so http://example.com/page/00001/ is now http://example.com/index.php?id=00001 instead of http://example.com/page.php?id=00001
Is it possible for it to also take into account the second one?

Comment: In case of `http://example.com/page/00001/` both rewrite rules would apply. What kind of information would you put behind the last slash ?

Comment: http://example.com/page/00001/_img/ or whatever which should 'redirect' to http://example.com/_img/. Basically, I want http://example.com/page/00001/ to redirect to http://example.com/page.php but anything else just to be http://example.com/whatever

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, it turns out I had it wrong. It should be this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/$ page.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/(.*) $2
```

This makes http://example.com/page/00001/ actually link to http://example.com/page.php?id=00001 but anything else - like http://example.com/page/00001/_img/image.jpg use the real URL which would be http://example.com/_img/image.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Mayby something like this would work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ $2
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/?$ /page.php?id=$1
```